# How to put control id based on parent control reference/ID to avoid conflict

Tags: html, jira

i am facing one issue due to one button control existed with same ID at two place in single page.

As i have created a custom field for jira which is appear on issue view screen and edit screen both.
"Edit" screen is just be a DIV and appear as display none till edit is clicked else issue view screen is appear  (both on single page).
my created button existed on both the area.

How can we keep the condition like - 
if parent is "DIV - edit" then keep different ID of button 
ELSE
another ID of button.  ? or any another way of jquery to resolve this conflict issue.

Below is stuff which shows same control at two place:

issue view screen stuff on a page:

```
.... .....
<li id="rowForcustomfield_11200" class="item">
<div class="wrap">
    <strong title="final Dynamic Value" class="name">final Dynamic Value:</strong>
    <div id="customfield_11200-val" class="value type-dynamicvalue editable-field active"
        data-fieldtype="dynamicvalue">
        <form id="customfield_11200-form" class="ajs-dirty-warning-exempt" action="#">
        <div class="inline-edit-fields">
            <div class="field-group">
                <table id="customfield_11200:maintable">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr width="15%">
                            <tr width="15%">
                                <tr width="15%">
                                    <tr width="15%">
                                        <tr width="15%">
                                            <tr width="15%">
                                                <tr width="15%">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="button" value="add" id="finaladd" />**PROBLEM CONTROL**
                <input type="button" value="remove" id="finalremove" />**PROBLEM CONTROL**
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="overlay-icon throbber" />
        <div class="save-options" tabindex="1">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</li>
...... 
 ....
  ..
```

note: i have highlighted above with tag comment as "**PROBLEM CONTROL**

Another stuff on same page for edit issue screen div:

```
  .......
.............
 <div id="edit-issue-dialog" class="aui-popup box-shadow aui-dialog-open popup-width-custom aui-dialog-content-ready"
style="width: 810px; margin-left: -405px; margin-top: -263.5px;">
<h2 class="aui-popup-heading">
    <div class="aui-popup-content">
        <div class="qf-container">
            <div class="qf-unconfigurable-form">
                <form action="#" name="jiraform" class="aui">
                <div class="form-body" style="max-height: 419px;">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="11100" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="atl_token" value="BP8Q-WXN6-SKX3-NB5M|6533762274aaa5d16f14dbbe010917f161596d8d|lin" />
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="aui-tabs horizontal-tabs" id="horizontal">
                            <ul class="tabs-menu">
                                <div class="tabs-pane" id="tab-0">
                                    <div class="tabs-pane active-pane" id="tab-1">
                                        <div class="field-group aui-field-something">
                                            <div class="field-group">
                                                <div class="field-group">
                                                    <div class="field-group">
                                                        <label for="customfield_11200">
                                                            final Dynamic Value</label>
                                                        <table id="customfield_11200:maintable">
                                                            <input type="button" value="add" id="finaladd" />  **PROBLEM CONTROL**
                                                            <input type="button" value="remove" id="finalremove" />  **PROBLEM CONTROL**
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="field-group aui-field-wikiedit comment-input">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="buttons-container form-footer">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 .....
 ...
   ..
```

NOTE: above highlighted issue at **PROBLEM CONTROL** tag comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can differentiate by using the id edit-issue-dialog

```
if($("#edit-issue-dialog").length){
//u r in edit form, and do your stuff
}else{
//in create form do your stuff
}
```